# Unable to boot into Windows 8.1 after repeated bsod

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod, lenovo-laptop, chkdsk, sfc

I have a 6yr old Lenovo laptop. It suddenly started giving me repeated blue screen on trying to startup, and I wasn't able to boot into Windows at all. I created a Windows 8.1 ISO on USB flash drive and tried the following after booting into it:

1. `Refresh` the Windows installation. This gives me the error `The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again`
2. From the command prompt ran `chkdsk` and `sfc`. Both are giving me errors.

`chkdsk C: /f /x /r` gives me `A disk read error occurred c00185. Insufficient disk space to fix ...Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log...`.

`sfc /scannow` gives me `Windows resource protection could not perform the required operation.`

`sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows` gives me `Windows resource protection could not start the repair service`.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*chkdsk ... gives me a disk read error*

This is an indication of a hard drive failure.

The drive is likely accessible from the side of the machine. Remove the drive, put it in a USB hard drive carrier, and plug into a working computer.

Can you see the contents of the hard drive?

Comment: I am actually not equipped to remove the hard drive unfortunately.

Comment: Go to Lenovo.com > Support and enter the model or serial number of the machine. Look for the Hardware Maintenance Manual and look through that. There is normally just a small screw holding the drive cover and you can access the drive there. Since it does look like a drive error, you also may wish to visit a local computer store who could help you